# Echoing users by groups, PHP

Tags: php, database

What I want to do is click a name of a group(every group what I create other than poweruser and admin groups) and that will echo all of the users in that group from the database. How will I be able to do this in php?

My code so far is:

```
include('db.php');
if (isset($_GET["groupID"])) {
$sql="SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE groupName <> 'poweruser' AND groupName <> 'admin' AND groupID = " . $_GET["groupID"] ;
} else {
$sql="SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE groupName <> 'poweruser' AND groupName <> 'admin'" ;
}
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection);
while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<a href='index.php?page=groups&group=".$line['groupID']."'>".$line['groupName'].'</a><br />';
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: ehhh [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) much?

Comment: Besides the obvious sql vulnerability, what's wrong with the code so far?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your code correctly, what you're doing here will output each of the groups' name.  To get the users you'd have to do something like this:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM `users` JOIN `group` ON `user`.`groupID` = `group`.`groupID` WHERE `users`.`groupID` = "'.$_GET["groupID"]'"';
```